# Simple animation with Tkinter Python

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I've searched for a simple animation code with Tkinter but I've found very different examples and I can't understand the correct way to write an animation. 
Here my working code to display a simple moving circle:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root=tk.Tk()
canvas=tk.Canvas(root,width=400,height=400)
canvas.pack()
circle=canvas.create_oval(50,50,80,80,outline="white",fill="blue")

def redraw():
   canvas.after(100,redraw)
   canvas.move(circle,5,5)
   canvas.update()
canvas.after(100,redraw)
root.mainloop()
```

In this code I can't correctly understand: how the after method works, where correctly put the update and the move method (before after method ?), is there another way to write an animation code? may you post me another example and comment the code please?
Thanks :)

Comment: the update is doing nothing, what do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: I need a simple animation, create a polygon and move it in my app

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it doesn't do nothing -- it actually does something. It processes all pending events.

Comment: @BryanOakley, what effect does it have in the OP's code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Like I said, it processes all pending events. In this specific case it's harmless since there are no event bindings, but "harmless" isn't the same as "nothing" because it actually does process any pending events. It does the same work as `mainloop`, but it does it just once rather than continually.

Answer (score 1):

**Calling `update`**

You should not call `canvas.update()`. As a general rule of thumb you should *never* call `update`. For a short essay on why, see [this essay](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful) written by one of the original developers of the underlying tcl interpreter.

If you take out the call to `canvas.update()`, you have the proper way to do animation in a tkinter program.

**Calling `after` to start the animation**

You don't need to call `after` immediately before calling `root.mainloop()`. This works just as well:

```
...
redraw()
root.mainloop()
```

The choice to use or not use `after` in this specific case is dependent on if you want the animation to start immediately (possibly even before the widget is visible) or if you want it to happen after a short delay (possibly after the widget is made visible)

**How `after` works**

`mainloop` is nothing more than an infinite loop that checks the event queue for events. When it finds an event, it pops it off of the list and processes it. `after` is nothing more than making a request that says "in 100 ms, please add a new event to the queue". When the time limit expires, an event is added to the queue that says, in effect, "run this command". The next time the loop checks for events, it sees this event, pulls it off of the queue, and runs the command.

When you call `after` from within a method that itself was called by `after`, you're saying in effect "wait 100ms and do it again", creating an infinite loop. If you put the call to `after` before moving the object, you're saying "every 100ms run this function". If you put it after you're saying "run this function 100 ms after the last time it was run". The difference is very subtle and usually not perceptible unless your function takes a long time to run.

Comment: Is there a reason why you should never call `.update`? It seems like a pretty useful thing to use to force an animation to be shown on the screen if you're changing things within a loop, for example making a loading screen.

Comment: @RedstoneReforged: [this essay](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful) by someone who wrote some of the internals of the underlying tcl interpreter is probably the best explanation there is.

Answer (score 0):

my code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
tk = Tk()
płótno = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
płótno.pack()
płótno.create_polygon(10,10,10,70,70,10,fill="blue",outline="black")
for x in range(0,51):
   płótno.move(1,5,0)
   płótno.update()
   rest(0.05)
```

płótno means canvas